# Misunderstanding about the definition of a limit (Spivak Calculus)

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, trigonometry, epsilon-delta

In Spivak's text, I quote:

"In general, if $\epsilon > 0$ to ensure that $|x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})| < \epsilon$ we need only require that $|x| < \epsilon$ and $x \ne 0$"

This can easily be proven false if $|x| < |x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})|$ Then how is it true; let's **try** to work it out.

$|x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})| < \epsilon$  means $-\epsilon < x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x}) < \epsilon$

$|x| < \epsilon$ means $-\epsilon < x < \epsilon$

How does this then prove the latter idea?

Comment: Which statement are you referring to?

Comment: How can $|x|$ be less than $|x^2\sin(1/x)|$?  If we divide both sides of that inequality by $|x|$, we get $1<|x\sin(1/x)|$.  But $1$ will not be less than $|x\sin(1/x)|$ if $x$ is near $0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, thanks for the response. It says, 

$|x^2sin(1/x)| < \epsilon$ then we need $|x| < \epsilon$

How can you prove that 

$|x^2sin(1/x)| > |x|$?

Comment: It doesn't say we _need_ $|x|<\varepsilon$; it says "we need only require $|x|<\varepsilon$".  The word "only" means we don't need to assume anything more than that about $x$ in order to deduce that $|x^2\sin(1/x)|<\varepsilon$.  In other words, it can be shown is that _if_ $|x|<\varepsilon$, _then_ $|x^2\sin(1/x)|<\varepsilon$.  In order to show that, it is enough to notice that $|\sin(1/x)|\le 1$ and so $|x^2\sin(1/x)|\le x^2 < |x| < \varepsilon$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, thanks, this makes better sense. So in all this, your initial assumption is that $|x| < \epsilon$ and you must deduce something from that. How would you know $x^2 > |x|$ though?

Comment: @Amad27 Does Spivak somewhere restrict $\varepsilon \leqslant 1$?

Comment: Not really, though most of his examples are $\epsilon < 1$

Comment: Without that restriction, $\lvert\sin\frac{1}{x}\rvert \leqslant 1$ is not sufficient to deduce $\lvert x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}\rvert < \epsilon$ from $\lvert x\rvert < \epsilon$ and $x\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says "to ensure that $|x^2\sin(1/x)|<\varepsilon$ we need ONLY require that $|x|<\varepsilon$ and $x\ne0$" (emphasis added).

What that actually means is that IF $|x|<\varepsilon$ and $x\ne0$ THEN  $|x^2\sin(1/x)|<\varepsilon$.

Notice that $|x^2\sin(\cdots)|\le|x^2|<|x|$ if $|x|<1$ (since $|\sin(\cdots)|\le1$).  So if $|x|<\varepsilon$ then $|x^2\sin(1/x)|<\varepsilon$ unless $x=0$.

Answer (score 3):

The missing part is

$$\left\lvert x \sin \left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right)\right\rvert \leqslant 1$$

for $x \neq 0$. That follows from the inequality $\lvert \sin y\rvert \leqslant \lvert y\rvert$ by setting $y = \frac{1}{x}$. Hence

$$\left\lvert x^2 \sin \left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right)\right\rvert \leqslant \lvert x\rvert$$

for $x\neq 0$.

Comment: I find this very strange. Why use the inequality $|\sin y|\le|y|$ when $y$ is a HUGE number and one could use the far simpler and far stronger inequality $|\sin y|\le 1$? The substantial content of the inequality $|\sin y|\le|y|$ is present only if one considers values of $y$ that are somewhat close to $0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: That inequality is used for small $\lvert y\rvert$, namely $\lvert x\rvert > 1$, I expect. If $\varepsilon \leqslant 1$, then of course $\lvert x^2\sin \frac{1}{x}\rvert \leqslant \lvert x\rvert^2 < \varepsilon^2$ is better. But if $\varepsilon > 1$, we need $\lvert x\sin \frac{1}{x}\rvert \leqslant 1$ to get that $\lvert x\rvert < \varepsilon$ is sufficient, @MichaelHardy.

Comment: Does it matter what happens when $|x|>1$?  I would think this is about a limit as $x\to0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, it is almost certainly about the limit as $x\to 0$. But I have the impression that Spivak avoided the restriction to demand $\varepsilon \leqslant 1$, because one doesn't need that. If you don't have the restriction $\varepsilon \leqslant 1$ the estimate $\lvert \sin \text{whatever}\rvert \leqslant 1$ requires $\lvert x\rvert < \sqrt{\varepsilon}$ (which of course for $\varepsilon < 1$ is an even weaker constraint on $x$).

Comment: Well, I don't really thing large values of $x$ are worth any attention in this problem.  And it is somewhat more complicated to do it this way.

Comment: Well. But then you need to explicitly require $\varepsilon \leqslant 1$ at some place. Maybe Spivak does that, maybe not.

Comment: Maybe one should say "for all sufficiently small $\varepsilon$". ${}\qquad{}$